# on click of multiple elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<div id="d1">
   <div id="d2"></div>
   <div id="d3"></div>
   <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is in which ever of the above element is clicked call this function:

```
function clickedele(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
}
```

I tried these But none worked:

```
var mhele_1 = $('#d1');
var mhele_2 = $('#d2');
var mhele_3 = $('#d3');
var menu_ico =$('#d4');
$([menu_ico.get(0),mhele_1.get(0), mhele_2.get(0),mhele_3.get(0)]).on('click', function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

or

```
$('#menu_ico,#d1, #d2,#d3').on()
```

or

```
$('#menu_ico').add('#d1').add('#d2').add('#d3').on()
```

But none worked

Comment: whu not use a class for all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your selector `#menu_ico` does not point to the element the element ids are `d1`, `d2` and `d3` so combine the id selectors and bind click event handler.

```
$('#d2,#d3,#d4').on('click', function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

```js
$('#d2,#d3,#d4').on('click', function() {
  alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">a</div>
  <div id="d3">b</div>
  <div id="d4">c</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** If the elements are dynamically added then use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
// assumes `#d1` is not dynamically added,
// if yes then use any of it's ancestor present
$('#d1').on('click', '#d2,#d3,#d4', function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

```js
$('#d1').on('click', '#d2,#d3,#d4', function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">a</div>
  <div id="d3">b</div>
  <div id="d4">c</div>
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** Use your code within [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to run after elements are loaded or add code at the end of the page.

---

**UPDATE 2:** The better approach would be using a common class for all elements and bind the handler to that.

```js
$('.d').on('click', function() {
  alert("Ele clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2" class="d">a</div>
  <div id="d3" class="d">b</div>
  <div id="d4" class="d">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I'm sorry for my late reply, I had to debug my code a little to find the porblem, which I found that when ever you click say d2|d3|d4 it also triggers d1 too || If you click d2 it also triggers d1. so it pop 2 alert boxes. do you know a way to trigger it once when ever an inner element of d1 is clicked?

Comment: @Mr.Nobody : Try `$('#d2,#d3,#d4').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Ele clicked");
});` use [`event.stoppropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j8g4pfrz/    So say `d` elements r used as button and on click the black menu should be poped up and on click again it should disappear

Comment: @Mr.Nobody : https://jsfiddle.net/j8g4pfrz/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/j8g4pfrz/2/ (it should be `css()` to get css value not `attr()`) where `attr('display')` would be `undefined`

Comment: @Mr.Nobody :  glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Event Delegation should be the way to go.

```js
$('#d1').on('click', clickFunc)

function clickFunc(e) {
  alert($(e.target).text())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">1</div>
  <div id="d3">2</div>
  <div id="d4">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clickedele() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
$('div[id^="d"]').on('click',clickedele);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
   <div id="d2"></div>
   <div id="d3"></div>
   <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

use `$('div[id^="d"]')` to select all div with id starting with `d` you can use any other pattern also like `$('#d1 > div[id^="d"]')` to select all div with id starting with `d` inside `d1` div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.common').click(clickedele)

function clickedele() {
  alert("click from " + $(this).text())
  alert("Ele clicked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2" class="common">1</div>
  <div id="d3" class="common">2</div>
  <div id="d4" class="common">3</div>
</div>
```

1. Add class common to all.
2. Use class to click

```js
$('#d1 div').click(clickedele)

function clickedele() {
  alert("click from " + $(this).text())
  alert("Ele clicked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2" class="common">1</div>
  <div id="d3" class="common">2</div>
  <div id="d4" class="common">3</div>
</div>
```

1. Use the parent as selector then add space and div meaning child of parent select like `$('#d1 div')`

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div id="d1">
   <div id="d2" onclick="isClicked(this)">d2</div>
   <div id="d3" onclick="isClicked(this)">d3</div>
   <div id="d4" onclick="isClicked(this)">34</div>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
function isClicked(obj){
   alert(obj.id);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/dyzgcju5/

Answer (score 0):

You can give child divs a common class. Lets suppose the class name is childDiv. Then you can handle the click event of the divs.

```
$(".childDiv").on("click",function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Its better to use a loop for that:

```
$('#d1 > div').each(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
 });
});
```

Comment: No it is not better to loop when you can do  `$('#d1 > div').on("click",function(){
    alert("Ele clicked");
 });` - which by the way misses d1 too